# SQLALCHEMY: subquery from raw sql with asyncSession

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, fastapi

Note: I am using asyncSession, so there is no "query" method attached to it.

I am trying to make following subquery (named as distant subquery):

```
With some_table as 
      (Select asset_id, {some_math_functions} as distance from table)
SELECT * from some_table where distance < threshold
```

After making the subquery, I want to join this subquery with other queries, and do some more operations there.

```
select(selections).join(
    table1, table1.model_id == models.id).join(
    ..................).join(
    ..................).join(
    distance_subquery, distance_subquery.asset_id == table1.asset_id)
```

And then perform final asyncsession.execute(selections.filter(..).order(...))

I have not found good resources where I can use subquery from raw sql and use it with other subqueries in sqlAlchemy. Any help will be highly appreciated.